# Recording in Linux

Tags: fedora, sip, ivr

In Fedora 12, what is available FREE, so that i can record my voice as G711u/a or GSM or G729 audio codec's.

Thanks in advance.

N.b: Tried gnome-sound-recorder 2.28.5 but it save file as WAV but doesn't allow to formet as ulaw or other audio codec's

Comment: This is not a question, and it is not about programming problems.

Comment: Well, it is a _question_, disregarding the lack of a question mark.

Comment: @Johan: I am not sure, if u learned in web only telling people this? I want to put a IVR system which can accept G711ulaw or alaw or GSM as wav formet. 

I am not yet came to a program which can do it. Audacity also not accepting.

Comment: It's still not a programming question. This is not the correct forum. Try superuser.com.

Comment: Anyway thanks found it and works with Server IVR, http://shamuntoha.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/recording-file-in-linux-for-ivr-g711ulaw-alaw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg -i audio.wav -acodec gsm -ab 192k audio.gsm

you need libgsm and ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can record a WAV file and then convert it to g711 format with the `sox` application.

Answer (score 0):

[**Audacity**](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)

> Audacity is free, open source software for recording and editing sounds. It is available for Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows, GNU/Linux, and other operating systems.